# Cordova media plugin seekTo doesn't work the first time

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm playing an audio through the cordova-plugin-media using the seekTo method.

```
media.play();
media.seekTo(time);
```

In Android it works fine but in iOS the first time I play, it ignores the seekTo specified and starts at the beginning. If the same media object is played again it works fine.

If I delay the seekTo call it works:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  media.seekTo(time);
}, 100);
```

Using 100 ms, it seems to work always, but I don't like this approach.

Any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a delay doesn't work always either.

I ended up listening to the `Media.MEDIA_RUNNING` status and calling `seekTo` from there.

It works fine now.

EDIT:

A snippet:

```
new Media(audio, function(){
    // Finished
  },
  function(){
    // Error
  },
  function(status){
    // State changed

    if (Media.MEDIA_RUNNING==status) {
        media.seekTo(start);
    }
});
```

Comment: This also happens on Android. Listening to ``Media.MEDIA_RUNNING`` is a good workaround.

Comment: @TanaseButcaru would you mind sharing a code example how you did that, listening to the MEDIA_RUNNING status on iOS and calling seekTo from there? I'm facing the exact same issue right now..thanks